# Find the "largest" negative integer $x$ which satisfies simultaneously $x\equiv 10\mod6$ and $(x:150)=10$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was trying this congruence's problem. My approach was using these facts: $$6k=x-10$$ $$(x:150)=10 \implies 10=mx+n150$$
Couldn't see what is the next step, I know $150=6*25$ so I can get to:
$$10=mx+(25n)6$$
What I'am missing?, I also know the fact that $(x:6)|10$ because I assume the congruence satisfies.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?  You have a system of congruences modulo $2$, $3$, and $25$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Not really, I've seen some videos, but the exercise requires that you use only the tools I know at that point (that is the definitions of congruence and divisibility, linear congruence and prime properties, bezout's).

Comment: Am I misinterpreting the problem?  The largest *candidate* negative integer is $-2$.  Then, $$-2 \equiv 10 \pmod{6}$$ and $$10 = \left[(-2) \times 70\right] + \left[(150) \times 1\right].$$

Comment: Does $(x:150)=10$ mean $x\equiv10\bmod{150}$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, $(a:b)=d$ is the notation of the common divisor between $a$ and $b$, so its equivalent to $GCD(a,b)=d$

Comment: @user2661923 Sorry but what steps can I use to get to that result?

Comment: Before answering that, I need to know:  is the correct answer $(-2)$?  That is, have I interpreted the problem correctly?

Comment: @user2661923 sorry I misread, it has to be the largest (close to 0) and at the same time the great common divisor between $x$ and $150$ has to be $10$, so it's not 2 (I don't have the answer sadly, it's a random exercise)

So technically it's not -2 because $GCD(-2,150)$ is not $10$.

Comment: The only candidates are $\{-2, -8. -14, -20, -26, -32, -38, \cdots\}.$ Trying each of $\{-2,-8,-14\}$ you see that none of those is divisible by $(10).$  Then, ask yourself, what about the **next** candidate, $(-20)$?

Comment: @user2661923 How do I get the -2 analytically to begin with?.

Comment: Because $6$ is a divisor of $[10 - (-2)].$

Comment: @user2661923 O I see so by saying $x\equiv 10\mod6$ I can safely assume that $(x:6)|10$ using $x$ and that the only possible chance is that the GCD is a even number, so it has to be -2? I don't really know how to justify, but I see the logic behind it! thanks.

Comment: No, I manually tested each of $\{-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6\}$ knowing that there had to be exactly one element in that set that was congruent to $10$ mod $6$.

Comment: @user2661923 Shouldn't that be positive numbers from 0 to 5? so you tried with each remainder first and just substract $6$ until the number is divisible by $10$?, I say positive numbers because the remainder of $-2$ its $4$ so the equivalence class is $[4]$.

Comment: I was using a shortcut.  The first step was to find the largest negative integer that was congruent to $10$ mod $6$.  I knew that this integer had to be some element in $\{-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6\}.$  These were my candidate values for the largest negative integer congruent to $10$ mod $6$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\gcd(x,150)=10\iff x=10y \;\text{and}\;\gcd(y,15)=1,$$for some integer $y.$

$10y\equiv10\bmod6\iff5y\equiv5\bmod3\iff y\equiv1\bmod3.$

The largest negative integer $y\equiv1\bmod3$ is $-2,$ and it is coprime to $15.$

So the answer is $x=10\cdot(-2)=-20.$